# Was that all you wanted?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A friend, who I haven't seen much lately because of a fall out, comes to my apartment. I let him in.

Me: What do you want?

Friend: I just came to pick up the book I lent you.

I give him the book. He hesitates to leave, so I ask:

Me: **So was that all you wanted?**

Friend: No, actually, I also came to give you an apology.

Question: Would the bold-face sentence be correct and natural to mean "So was that all you came for"? (if that's correct as well)

Comment: Yes, it would be correct if not exactly courteous. You might equally phrase it in the present tense: **So, is that all you want(ed)**. Both are natural.

Comment: @RonaldSole That seems like an answer to me!

Comment: When saying 'was that all you wanted?, there might be, depending on tone of voice and the circumstances, an implication of 'I hope you wanted [to say] more', or 'you have left things unsaid', or an implied encouragement to say something that the other person might be hesitant about.